# Where did the space-suit design used in Mobile Suit Gundam by the Zeons originate, or did it originate from Gundam?

Tags: history-of, costume, clothing, mobile-suit-gundam, design

As the title says. I swear I've seen sci-fi art from before then that had similar suit designs, seen [here](http://www.gundam-the-origin.net/en/character/0401.html), and I'm curious of who came up with it originally. It's sort of difficult to find other examples since this particular design doesn't exactly have a name for it, but I'm sure someone would know what I'm referring to. After all, the Zeon's mobile suits were based off of the power suit designs for the Japanese cover of *Starship Troopers*.

Comment: They are kind of reminiscent of Star Wars?

Comment: The purple ones (if that's purple, I am kind of colorblind) in the third row look like  MCU Thanos.